# visually enhanced joomla 2.5 List of Categories component (Default is ugly)

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla-component

I have a menu item that loads a List of Categories.

The problem is that I don´t know if there is a visually enhaced component other than the default one.

Could you please point me to the right direction
I am using Joomla 2.5

Printscreen: http://snag.gy/pEQsb.jpg

Comment: you can create a template override of joomla's default categories list output and style it as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add a link to the suggestion from Marko D about template overrides (which would be the correct answer):
http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core and http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides explains how the template overrides work

This is indeed the simplest way to adjust how the list is created. And of course using CSS within your template.